# Why Stripe webhook does work by using of terminal and doesn't work without terminal?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, http-status-code-503

I've made a php end-point http://site/stripe-webhooks with code from the Following example "http://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build".

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Stripe Webhooks
 */


$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_****************************************';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.created':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        // handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
        $session = $event->data->object;

        // Fulfill the purchase...
        handle_checkout_session($session);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);
```

When I write `stripe listen --forward-to http://site/stripe-webhooks` in the terminal and test my payment process, it works.

But if I close the terminal, it doesn't work. When I send a test event to webhook endpoint via dashboard, I receive the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

The page exists and it can be opened in a browser. Where is the mistake?

Comment: If you make POST requests to the webhook URL, do they work?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to make such tests for stripe webhook. Could you give an example?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: I've checked it. It looks like POST requests works. I do not know which params I must send. But I have a code in webhook which save Post request in my database. This code works.